# Why build so big sarcophagus in Chernobyl instead another alternative?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

As title, why build so big sarcophagus in Chernobyl? The new sarcophagus is really tall, large and expensive and it should cover the old one. But there is already a sarcophagus build over another structure(reactor), so it's something like a matroska. Wasn't better to demolish all, without raising too much dust, and create some kind of pool and fill it with some kind of filler material? I suppose it's faster and less expensive. But since they preferred to do this kind of project, what are complications that led them to decide to cover old sarcophagus with another one instead of proceed in another way?

Comment: +1 excellent question. Welcome to physics.stackexchange.

Comment: Imagine you are the person opening the sarcophagus in order to demolish it. What is protecting you from radiation until the new one is built?

Comment: according to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_New_Safe_Confinement the old sarcophagus is unstable, the whole thing is still highly radioactive and has to be contained in order not to spread to the environment . The goals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_New_Safe_Confinement#Design_goals  include eventual demolition.

Comment: The problem is 'demolish the old one without raising too much dust': that's impractical, so it is easier to just wrap it all in another one.